Incorrect indentation after a do-while loop with a double-line function call and an array parameter in C++
This can be reproduced using vim --clean.
Here's a simplified example of my code:
{
    do {
        a(b[i],
                c);
    } while (d);
    e;
}

However, Vim indents the line with e; by two levels, like this:
{
    do {
        a(b[i],
                c);
    } while (d);
        e; // this line indented two levels instead of one.
}

Here are some other examples of Vim indentation results:
No do-while, correct:
{
    {
        a(b[i],
                c);
    }
    e;
}

No b[i], correct:
{
    do {
        a(b,
                c);
    } while (d);
    e;
}

a called in a single line, correct:
{
    do {
        a(b[i], c);
    } while (d);
    e;
}

Is it a Vim bug?

Can you reproduce with vim --clean? If I do, I get overindentation on the line with c); as well.

@Friedrich That is what cino+=(0 do, which controls indent for line with the unclosed parenthesis. It's a correct behavior.

BTW, stackoverflow seems to replace "\t" with 4 spaces.

Okay, I muddled two points into one. Let's try again. Readers of your question cannot know which other options you have set. Note that set cino+=... adds  to whatever was already in cino. That means you need to tell us the values of everything mentioned in :help C-indentation or you start from a well-defined base like vim --clean (with :version). The same rules apply on Vim's issue tracker, should you choose to raise it there.
